# Where can I see a list of reviews where I have approved but it was rejected and vise-versa?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, review-audits

I recently got review ban for failing single audit, which would imply that I wasn't doing fair work for a while - since as I understand one does not get banned for single failed audit.
To better understand on what is expected quality for a post I would like to see where I was to forgiving of harsh.

Where can I see a list of reviews where I have approved but it was rejected and vise-versa?

**UPDATE:** [Here I have made miserable attempt](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209172/rejected-reviews-that-i-have-approved-and-vise-versa?UserId=1509764) to tweak query from the post below to give list of links to posts with opinion disagreements on reviews only.

Comment: I fear that only Data Explorer can give such analysis.

Comment: Looking at a list of edits you rejected that were approved is just going to be super depressing in which you see a ton of completely inappropriate edits approved by people who either didn't read the edits, didn't understand what was going on, didn't look close enough to see why they were inappropriate, or simply don't know what an inappropriate edit is.  It's likely to sap the enthusiasm for reviewing right out of you.  For your own good, stick to edits you approved that were rejected.  There you'll mostly find things that you just missed.

Comment: @Servy where could I find such a list?

Comment: @LIUFA [You need to go see The Wizard.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236690/where-can-i-see-a-list-of-reviews-where-i-have-approved-but-it-was-rejected-and?noredirect=1#comment775943_236690)

Comment: @Servy endless loop?

Comment: @LIUFA after a quick look in the data, it's not trivial to construct such a query, but should be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that this isn't really useful on most sites, as you only have one person that agrees or disagrees with your review decision, which will probably make for a lot of false positives.

On sites where there are three reviewers for suggested edit reviews, there is [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/206296/suggested-edits-voting-compared-to-final-result) which was created by [Stijn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/247702/stijn) as a result of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262619/how-many-approved-posts-have-been-rejected) on Meta Stack Overflow:

```
select
  count(*) as ApprovedByUserAndApprovedAsFinalResult
from
  SuggestedEdits se
  inner join SuggestedEditVotes sev on sev.SuggestedEditId = se.Id
where
  sev.UserId = ##UserId##
  and se.ApprovalDate is not null
  and sev.VoteTypeId = 2 -- UpMod

select
  count(*) as RejectedByUserAndRejectedAsFinalResult
from
  SuggestedEdits se
  inner join SuggestedEditVotes sev on sev.SuggestedEditId = se.Id
where
  sev.UserId = ##UserId##
  and se.RejectionDate is not null
  and sev.VoteTypeId = 3 -- DownMod

select
  count(*) as ApprovedByUserAndRejectedAsFinalResult
from
  SuggestedEdits se
  inner join SuggestedEditVotes sev on sev.SuggestedEditId = se.Id
where
  sev.UserId = ##UserId##
  and se.RejectionDate is not null
  and sev.VoteTypeId = 2 -- UpMod

select
  count(*) as RejectedByUserAndApprovedAsFinalResult
from
  SuggestedEdits se
  inner join SuggestedEditVotes sev on sev.SuggestedEditId = se.Id
where
  sev.UserId = ##UserId##
  and se.ApprovalDate is not null
  and sev.VoteTypeId = 3 -- DownMod
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to see this from your profile, except by going through your activity tab and opening the review items one by one.

If you mean suggested edit reviews, then the following queries on the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) probably are either what you want or a good start to get the output that you want.

- [My contested suggested edit reviews](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79860/my-contested-suggested-edit-reviews)
- [My overruled suggested edit reviews](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/79859/my-overruled-suggested-edit-reviews)

Comment: Hi Gilles. This gives me really good insight on what should be approved or rejected especially in cases where I have voted in one direction and moderator voted in the other. Thank you.

Comment: Is this a mistake by community or am I missing something? http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5171981 To me this looks as a necessary formatting fix that should have been approved IMHO, (because of closing brackets being outside code section).

Comment: @LIUFA Reject by Community usually means that someone else with ≥2000 rep (i.e. whose edits are applied right away, not suggested) edited the post. Then your suggestion is automatically overridden. That's what happened here, check the [post history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24465718/revisions).

Comment: Oh I see, I was really getting worried if I understand anything about approving editing at all. BTW some of approves are really dangerous. One example would be when someone completely changes the code section (I saw it at least 3 times) and it gets rejected 2-3, which makes me wonder how often do good questions get vandalized this way.